# While I'm trying gcc make linux-headers-`uname -r` I'm getting error

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, kernel, ubuntu-20.04

I was trying to install droidcam Linux client. when I run the command

```
gcc make linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
gcc: error: make: No such file or directory
gcc: error: linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

and this tells me it is already there.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic is already the newest version (5.4.0-42.46).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

[From this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176621/droidcam-ubuntu-18-04-error) I just run this command `yes | sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module`

and then followed the other steps described.